# Zend_Auth not working

Tags: zend-framework, authorization

In my model, "Users", I have the following authorization after validating the username/password

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($db,'users','username','password');
$authAdapter->setIdentity($username);
$authAdapter->setCredential(md5($password));
$auth_result = $authAdapter->authenticate();

if( $auth_result->isValid() )
{
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $storage = $auth->getStorage();
    $storage->write($authAdapter->getResultRowObject(array('id','username')));

    return 'logged_in';
}
return 'auth_failed';
```

it keeps returning 'auth_failed'. I had the code running on a localhost, and everything works fine, but when I upload it online, it fails to authorize the user. What is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Have you synced the database with localhost and set the right user/password parameters in the config?

Comment: Yes! I can register and create users into that table.

Comment: You can register from the Application or thorugh phpmyadmin?

Comment: Through application... The registration form on my website works just fine and it creates the user. Its just when it wants to authorize the user that has a problem (it still verifies the username/password and then fails!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell what's wrong without checkin the logs, so perhaps you might want to use the method I use for storing auth data. Basically you validate manually and set the storageThis doesn't solve the problem, but its impossible to do so without accessing your code.

```
function login($userNameSupplied,$passwordSupplied){
$table= new Application_Model_Dbtable_Users();//Or Whatever Table you're using
$row=$table->fetchRow($table->select()->where('username=?',$userNameSupplied)->where('password=?',md5($passwordSupplied));
if($row){
Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->write($row->toArray());
return 'logged_in';
}
else{return 'failed';}
}


//To check if the user is logged in, use
$userInfo=Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->read();
if($userInfo)//user is logged in
```